# Is there a simple way to have optional output arguments in a python function?

Tags: python

I want to do something like the following.

I want to define a function func(), as:

```
def func(**kwargs):
    if 'a' in kwargs:
        a = funcA()
    if 'b' in kwargs:
        b = funcB()
    ...
```

or

```
def func(**kwargs):
    if 'a' in kwargs:
        kwargs['a'] = funcA()
    if 'b' in kwargs:
        kwargs['b'] = funcB()
    ...
```

where funcA() and funcB() are defined elsewhere. I want to then call the function func() with a variable number of arguments:

```
>>> func(a = x)
>>> func(b = y)
>>> func(a = x, b = y)
...
```

These calls should assign values to x, y, etc. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not sure what `a = funcA(a)` would allow you to do, but `func(funcA)` allows you to pass in function references as parameters.

Comment: "These calls should assign values to a, b, etc." - calling a function will not cause assignments to variables in the caller's scope. Also, those example calls are passing `a` and `b` positionally, so `func` wouldn't be able to tell which one is intended as `a` and which one is intended as `b`. Python's execution model doesn't work the way you're expecting. You'll need to get used to return values and the parameter passing mechanics.

Comment: Assigning to a parameter variable doesn't modify the variable that was used  to call the function.

Comment: `python3` or `python2`? 3 let's you do keyword-only arguments more easily and expressively.

Comment: @RyanHaining I want to do this in Python 2.7. If it can only be done well in Python 3.x, I'd like to hear about that, as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't modify the caller's variable by assigning to the parameter like that, you need to return a value with the `return` statement, and the caller can assign back to the variable.

```
def func(**kwargs):
    if 'a' in kwargs and 'b' in kwargs:
        return (funcA(kwargs['a']), funcB(kwargs['b']))
    elseif 'a' in kwargs:
        return funcA(kwargs['a'])
    elseif 'b' in kwargs:
        return funcB(kwargs['b'])

a = func(a = a)
b = func(b = b)
a, b = func(a = a, b = b)
```

A more general, scalable method would be to return a dictionary.

```
def func(**kwargs):
    retval = {}
    if 'a' in kwargs:
        retval['a'] = funcA(kwargs['a'])
    if 'b' in kwargs:
        retval['b'] = funcB(kwargs['b'])
    return retval

a = func(a = a)['a']
b = func(b = b)['b']
vals = func(a = a, b = b)
a = vals['a']
b = vals['b']
```

Comment: This is something like what I had in mind, but I want to avoid enumerating all the possible return combinations. Is there a way around that? I edited my question to hopefully be a little clearer about what I'm trying to do.

Comment: A more scalable method would be to return a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

As a general approach, for refusing of writing multiple `if` condition you better to create a dictionary of your arguments with their relative functions then class the relative function if the intended argument has been passed to the function caller:

```
def func(**kwargs):
    arg_dict = {'a': funcA, 'b': funcB}
    for arg, value in kwargs.items():
        try:
            yield arg_dict.get(arg)(value)
        except TypeError:
            # do stuff or just pass
```

This function will return a generator contain the values of relative functions for arguments.

Note that if you don't want to pass the value of your arguments instead of the aforementioned `arg_dict` you should use `arg_dict = {'a': funcA(), 'b': funcB()}` and just `yield` the `arg_dict.get(arg)`.

Answer (score 0):

You're using positional arguments when calling `func`, which do not pass in `**kwargs`.

Instead, you have to specify keyword arguments to `func` too.

Like this:

```
def func(**kwargs):
    if 'a' in kwargs:
        funcA(kwargs['a'])
    if 'b' in kwargs:
        funB(kwargs['b'])
```

And then:

```
func(a='hello')
func(b='thing')
func(a='hello', b='thing')
```

See the docs for [positional and keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-argument).